# Android CoordinatorLayout, Listview and fixed toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, coordinator-layout

I have a layout which has a toolbar in the top, followed by 2 toolbar sized bars under it and a listview below that. When someone scrolls on the listview, the 2 bars under the toolbar should scroll up and disappear under the toolbar.

I tried putting the app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" only on those bars and not the toolbar but then they doesn't respond to scroll events. 
If I put the same scrollFlags on the toolbar as well, they all respond but I want the toolbar to always display. 
If I move the two bars above the toolbar, it works and only the two bars respond, but now the toolbar is below the bars and this is not the display I want.

Comment: Post your layout xml code to get fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the Toolbar you want to stay still at the top below your appBar. Your AppBar contains the views that you actually want to scroll, while the other one will be below it. Make sure to have your app bar have an elevation of 0dp or else it will go and be displayed above it (or change the elevation of your toolbar to be higher than the appbar). Also add the Height of the bar you want to stay at the top as the top margin of the appbar so it starts out below you view.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">    

    <!--Toolbars you want to move-->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:elevation="2dp"
                />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--Toolbar you don't want to move-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/wallet_bright_foreground_holo_light"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        />

    <!--Your content here -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <include layout="@layout/item_list" />
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```